# What does selector.eventHandler(...some code...).eventHandler(...some code...) do in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I came across a jQuery snippet like this:

```
selector.eventHandler(...some code...).eventHandler(...some code...);
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a chain, since each `.eventHandler()` call returns a jQuery object (they're almost all shortcuts for [`.bind("event", func)`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)), you can continue to call functions on it...it's called [chaining](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain).